# Natural Decision Problem not in PTIME

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Are there any natural decision problems which are guaranteed not to be in $\mathsf{PTIME}$? Preferably natural graph problems like $\mathsf{CLIQUE}, \mathsf{VERTEXCOVER}$ etc. (However, they would be in $\mathsf{PTIME}$ if $\mathsf{PTIME}=\mathsf{NPTIME}$).

The [Time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) suggests a $\mathsf{EXPTIME}$ complete problem. Any graph problems which are $\mathsf{EXPTIME}$-complete?

Comment: Cops and robbers ! http://math.ryerson.ca/~wkinners/papers/crexptime.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to make manuellafond's comment to an answer:

"Cops and robbers" is a natural $\mathsf{EXPTIME}$-complete graph problem. Thus, there can be no polynomial time algorithm to decide the general "Cops and Robbers"-Problem.